# how to integrate a flex application into a rails environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache-flex, integration

I have a webpage based on ruby on rails. For one task I need some more complex user interface which I plan to do with a flex programm. The question is, how I can start the a new window with my flex programm and hand over the right url where the flex app can load its data in XML format...

Thanks in advance
Markus

Comment: Duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70524/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/135427/ & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253269/

Answer (score 1):

Remember that a Flex delivery is just a SWF file, with some extra magic around. You could just load it on a regular view or even a html file on the public directory and then have it talk with your Rails app.

We currently use Flex for charting some statistics and it was really painless to integrate. Since Rails favorites a RESTful approach, you can make your Flex app just call the right URIs for data and then work with the result (either JSON or XML).